# TextInput and dateFieldMask

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'd like to create a mask for both component textinput and datefield.

I'd like to do something like that

http://examples.adobe.com/flex2/exchange/MaskedTextInput/Reservation/Reservation.html

Thanks for helping

Comment: So, what is stopping you? :)  Your question is pretty open-ended - see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: I found example in Flex 2 and as I'm a beginner in Flex 4, is not easy to convert code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download a lot of components from [Adobes Flex Exchange](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=productHome&exc=15)

Examples of masked input components:

http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1049969
http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1616518

Good luck!